# MVT to prove an inequality

Tags: derivatives

> Use the Mean Value Theorem to prove that $|\cos a − \cos b| \leq |a − b|\,\forall a, b \in\mathbb R$.

Please advise if I am heading the right direction because I got stuck after doing this: 
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \cos x \\
f'(x) &= -\sin x \\
c &= |a-b| \\
-\sin|a-b| &=  \frac{|\cos a − \cos b|}{|a-b|}
\end{align}$$

Comment: MVT states that $\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}=f'(c)$ for some $c\in (a,b)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by MVT we have

$$\frac{|\cos a − \cos b|}{|a-b|}= |\sin c|\le 1$$

for some $c\in(a,b)$.

Comment: Thank you gimusi. Let me summarise, since $0 <= sin c <= 1$, $|cosa - cos b|$ cannot be greater than $|a-b|$?

Comment: @G.L. -- Sine can be negative, so you need either absolute value, or ${^-}1\leq\sin c\leq 1$.

Comment: @G.L. By MVT we have $\frac{\cos a − \cos b}{a-b}= -\sin c$ and taking the absolute value both sides $\frac{|\cos a − \cos b|}{|a-b|}= |\sin c|\le 1\implies |\cos a − \cos b|\le |a-b|$.

Comment: @mr_e_man Yes of course!

Comment: got it, thanks eveyone!

Comment: You are welcome! Bye

Comment: @G.L. -- If it answered your question, you're supposed to "accept" the answer with that check mark on the side.